# Getting names from facebook

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having a baby soon and I want to give him a unique/relatively less known name from my country. I want to get all names on facebook for a given country (say India) and then find 1000 least common names. I am not able to determine if Facebook API allows me to do this. Can someone suggest which APIs I should look at?

If it is not possible in FB, is it possible in any other social network?

Thanks.

Comment: You could probably look into [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com)

Comment: @JustinL.I looked at Wolfram Alpha. Its not giving anything useful. It is giving population statistcs for India.

Answer (score 1):

The Graph API. Although I think Graph API takes reference from a user and then search in his friends only or if he/she has a page then in their followers only. The users which are not connected to the user can not be accessed. I've never seen a function which can return all users or their userIDs.

Edit:-
Ok I've found that you might need the Open Graph API and the [Action Types,](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type) but their's no Action type for country.

Comment: Hmmm. In that case, is there another social network where I can get similar functionality?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. The closest you can do is an FQL query on the name table

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE contains('user763410baby')
```

Comment: I am studying this now. Will post it if I get anything useful.